# Is the Hopf fibration a fibration

Tags: algebraic-topology, hopf-fibration

By hopf fibration I mean the hopf map: $S^3\to S^2$. I could find references proving that it is a fiber bundle, but I would like to see a proof that it is an actual fibration.

(Here fibration mean that for any space $X$ and homotopy $F : X\times [0,1]\to S^{2}$, whenever $F_0$ has a lift $\tilde{h} : X\to S^{3}$ then $F$ has a lift $\tilde{F} : [0,1]\times S^2\to S^{3}$ with $\tilde{F}_0 = \tilde{h}$)

I'm completely new to fibrations, any reference or highlight of the ideas involved would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Every fiber bundle in the category of smooth manifolds is a fibration; see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415356/when-is-a-fibration-a-fiber-bundle. Usually one is interested in the other direction: given a fibration, is it "an actual fiber bundle"?